# ANDROID JSON Retrieve specific value of json data

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps-api-3

I want to retrieve the `administrative_area_level_1` value as the state, `locality` value as the area and `formatted_address` value as the address for further use. I use the google maps api where I give the latitude and longitude and it will return the json object which contain the data I want.

Below is the example of the url I use to retrieve the data with the part of result I want.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=1.56406166666667,103.626493333333&sensor=true

```
    {
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "Jalan Cengal",
                   "short_name" : "Jalan Cengal",
                   "types" : [ "route" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Johor Bahru",
                   "short_name" : "Johor Bahru",
                   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Johor",
                   "short_name" : "Johor",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Malaysia",
                   "short_name" : "MY",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "80990",
                   "short_name" : "80990",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "Jalan Cengal, 80990 Johor Bahru, Johor, Malaysia",
......
```

So at first this is my coding to retrieve the data I want.

```
private void extractPosition(JSONObject json)
{
    JSONObject result = json.optJSONArray("results").optJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray address_components = result.optJSONArray("address_components");

    area.setText(address_components.optJSONObject(1).optString("short_name"));

    state.setText(address_components.optJSONObject(2).optString("short_name"));

    address.setText(result.optString("formatted_address"));
}
```

But then I realize the position will not always be the same because some coordinates have additional info like the one below so I can't rely on the position of the data.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Jalan Kebudayaan 11",
               "short_name" : "Jalan Kebudayaan 11",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Taman Universiti",
               "short_name" : "Taman Universiti",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Skudai",
               "short_name" : "Skudai",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Johor",
               "short_name" : "Johor",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Malaysia",
               "short_name" : "MY",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "81300",
               "short_name" : "81300",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Jalan Kebudayaan 11, Taman Universiti, 81300 Skudai, Johor, Malaysia",
.....
```

How should I modify my coding so I can retrieve the  `administrative_area_level_1` and `locality` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void extractPosition(JSONObject json)
    {
        JSONObject result = json.optJSONArray("results").optJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray address_components = result.optJSONArray("address_components");

        for (int i =0; i<address_components.length();i++)
        {
            String searchKeyword;

            searchKeyword = address_components.optJSONObject(i).optString("types");
            Log.d("test", searchKeyword);

            if (searchKeyword.contains("locality"))
            {
                area.setText(address_components.optJSONObject(i).optString("short_name"));
            }

            if (searchKeyword.contains("administrative_area_level_1"))
            {
                state.setText(address_components.optJSONObject(i).optString("short_name"));
            }
        }

        address.setText(result.optString("formatted_address"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void extractPosition(JSONObject json)
{
    JSONObject result = json.optJSONArray("results").optJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray address_components = result.optJSONArray("address_components");

    for (int i =0; i<address_components.lenght;i++){

      if(address_components.optJSONObject(1).optString("short_name").equals("locality"))
        area.setText(address_components.optJSONObject(1).optString("short_name"));

      if (address_components.optJSONObject(1).optString("short_name").equals("administrative_area_level_1"))
        state.setText(address_components.optJSONObject(2).optString("short_name"));

      address.setText(result.optString("formatted_address"));
}
}
```